# Как вставить после каждого положительного элемента второго массива максимальный элемент из первого массива?

Tags: python, массивы, list

В первой части задания нужно было сгенерировать случайный список и убрать из него все двузначные числа, здесь всё ясно/понятно:

```
a = int(input("Введите число, которое будет началом диапазона случайных чисел: "))
b = int(input("Введите число, которое будет концом диапазона случайных чисел: "))
c = random.randint(0, 100) # длина последовательности целых чисел, к примеру, возьмем случайное число от 0 до 100

rndlist = [random.randint(a, b) for i in range(c)] # Создаем и заполняем список, состоящий из случайных чисел и длиной "c"

newlist = []

for i in rndlist:
    if -10 < i < 10:
        newlist.append(i)

print(newlist)
```

Далее нужно найти максимальное значение 1-го списка (rndlist)

```
maxvalue = max(rndlist)
```

И вставить maxvalue после каждого положительного элемента второго массива (newlist)

Здесь собственно и вся проблема, с которой и ищу помощи :)

Заранее крайне благодарен! :)

Comment: 2 последовательных цикла, первый находит максимум, второй вставляет его после положительных чисел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for i in range(len(newlist) - 1, -1, -1):  # Проходим по индексам с конца
    if newlist[i] > 0:  # Если положительный
        newlist.insert(i + 1, maxvalue)  # Вставляем после него
```